# Forms authentication failing when using SQL Server session state

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I been struggling with an issue lately. My website which is using forms authentication is behaving pretty wierd suddenly. Once forms authentication is timing out, I can see I'm logged out of my application but for some reason, I'm not getting redirected to the login page. This was working absolutely fine before. Not sure what has happened to it suddenly. I'm using SQL Server to store session state and when I made my application to inProc, everything looks fine.

I even deleted and recreated my ASP.NET Session state database but no luck yet. When I look into Event viewer, I have many entries with the following message:

"Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired."

On little search, someone said, this could happen with app pool recycling. I even deleted and recreated my app pool now. But still, I'm not getting redirected to login page.

Can someone help me out here.

Thank you.

Comment: What method are you using to prevent unauthenticated users from seeing pages?  A web.config element?  If so, can you post it?

Comment: Yes, I have been configuring from web.config. This is what I got now     <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" />
    </authentication>                                                And this is how Session state is configured                         <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" cookieName="CommerceSessionId" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="NewASPNET-State" timeout="60" />

Comment: Neither of those entries will prevent users from seeing pages even if they're not logged in.  Do you have an <authorization> element anywhere?

Comment: Yep, that would be why then.  Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Forms Authentication to actually block access to pages, you need to tell your application under what circumstances to block access.

This will block all users who aren't logged in and cause a redirect back to your specified login page.  Place it right after your `<authentication>` tag for simplicity.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" /> 
</authorization>
```

If you want to limit on more specific terms, you can add `<location>` elements with more detail.  See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) for more information.

Comment: It works now after some setting up the <location> element. Thank you.